# htaccess and rewrite - Internal redirect within Alias

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` within a subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file.js$ file.php
```

The directory, containing the above and other files looks like this:

```
dir/
├── index.html
└── js
    ├── file.php
    └── .htaccess
```

I want my `file.js` to be **internally redirected** to the `file.php`.

When I have `dir` under `/var/www/html/`, and my `vhost` definition looking like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
#Alias /dir "/tmp/dir"
#<Directory "/tmp">
#       AllowOverride All
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

**it works**!

However, when I move `dir` to `/tmp/` and change the `vhost` to look like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#<Directory "/var/www/html">
#    AllowOverride All
#     Require all granted
#</Directory>
Alias /dir "/tmp/dir"
<Directory "/tmp">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the **redirect does not work any more**, though I still can access other files such as `index.html`.

**The logs show me that the rewrite prepends the `DocumentRoot` to the full path of my `file.php` and, thus, giving me a *File does not exist* message**

Question:

**How do I write an .htaccess that is *agnostic* to where it is placed, and just makes an internal redirect from one specific file to another?**

Please keep in mind that, while I am able to change the the main `vhost` config to deal with this problem, **my goal is to do this using only `.htaccess`**.

Answer (score 1):

The [best practice](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) is to move your configuration directives to the actual Apache configuration file (and disallow .htaccess files completely).

In this case that will solve your problem because you're no longer dependent on a filesystem location for your directive to take effect...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    www.example.com
  ServerAlias   example.com
  DocumentRoot  /var/www/example.com/
  Alias /scripts/ /var/www/scripts/
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule   ^file.js$ file.php
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're not the system administrator and don't have access your Apache config, well, your question wouldn't be [on topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) but that's beside the point, you could solve the issue by creating a (copy) `.htaccess` file in the directory containing `file.js`. Depending on the `AllowOverride` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) the real administrator configured for you, you normally are allowed to place .htaccess file in any directory and subdirectory Apache has access to. You're not restricted to the DocumentRoot.

Comment: Please see my revised answer. I am specifically interested in knowing if this can be done using `.htaccess` files. Thank you anyway !!